# Retrieving database table info OOP

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to retrieve my database rows using OOP I keep getting an error though. I feel like I am missing something simple to make this work. My code is below:

```
Class CommentFactory {      
    public function getImage(PDO $conn){
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `pictures`');
        $stmt2->execute();

        return $stmt2;
    }
}


$statement = new CommentFactory();
$statement->getImage($conn);
while ($idOfComment = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $idOfComment['photo_id'];          
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CommentFactory::fetch() in /var/www/CommentSystem/includes/Classes.php on line 29`

I just recently began trying to program in OOP so my understanding is still vague.

Comment: Class `CommentFactory`  does not implement any such method

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an user error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only returning a value from the method `getImage()`, therefore you should do:

```
Class CommentFactory {

    protected $conn;

    public function getImage($conn){
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `pictures`');
        $stmt2->execute();

        return $stmt2;
    }
}


$statement = new CommentFactory();
$values = $statement->getImage($conn);
while ($idOfComment = $values->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $idOfComment['photo_id'];

}
```

Edit: However, as *engvrdr* noted, this is not the best you can do. You could the method to return the array, furthermore, you can pass the connection in the constructor as shown here:

```
Class CommentFactory {

    protected $conn;

    public function __construct($conn) {
      $this->con = $conn;
      }

    public function getImage(){
        $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `pictures`');
        $stmt2->execute();
        return $values->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}


$statement = new CommentFactory($conn);
foreach ($statement->getImage() as $Image){
    echo $Image['photo_id'];    
}
```

Comment: Thank you I actually got it working right after posting this so I will still accept your answer!

Comment: If you got it working without help, delete the question as it's unlikely to help future viewers...

Comment: But you understand why, right? If not I can elaborate further

Comment: @Francisco Presencia: Not any matters here, it's fixed, it was just holding the hand for a minute, the question and all answers can be dumped as this is "solved". I suggest to just leave comments in the future for such little mistakes.

Comment: No I understand I used `var_dump` on `$statement` and seen it did not contain the data I needed so I did exactly what you did and it worked fine

Comment: @Jimbo , I think it's still a perfectly valid question. You can answer your own question too, [it's even encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Furthermore, it's not a simple typo, it's was a mistake about OOP concepts.

Comment: @hakre I thought it'd be a bit messy to write those 2 lines of code and the sentence in a comment, but next time I will try.

Comment: Yes, it might be. However, it's really not worth on these questions I'd say, however you can always do however it pleases you.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia As expected, marked as dupe: it's worth searching SO first before answering, as the question may have an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

$statement variable is a instance of a CommentFactory class so it doesn't have a fetch method, that's why you are getting error.

you can either assign STMT object to a variable and loop through that variable like

```
$stmt = $statement->getImage();
while($id = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

But i don't advise you to do it.

First of all, injecting db connection to a object method doesn't feel right to me, you can inject the connection object while you are creating CommentFactory object like;

```
class CommentFactory{
    private $conn;
    public $images;

    public function __construct($connection){
        $this->conn = $connection;
    }

    public function getImage(){
        $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `pictures`');
        $stmt2->execute();
        while ($idOfComment = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $this->images[] = $idOfComment['photo_id'];

        }
    }

}

$statement = new CommentFactory($conn);
$statement->getImage();
foreach($statement->images as $photo_id)
    echo $photo_id;
}
```

by the way, if you mean Factory design pattern by naming like CommentFactory,i advise you to have a look at example at wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#PHP)

Comment: This is a great answer. Wish it had more attention. Why don't you just return the array of images straight away from `getImage()`? It feels kind of weird (to me) that you call `getImage()` and then access `$statement->images` directly.

Comment: Thank you, Actually as i am reading the code again it would be better to returning array of images but also assigning to $images so you can return same array if the same method called again and this would be better for performance too